# Puppeteer Error: Page Crashed! trying to get page with fully loaded body

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-scraping, puppeteer

When I **scrape** with `request` or `axios`, it doesn't have anything inside body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<!--Deleted Head content -->
</head>
<body>
    <ui-root></ui-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d13fzx7h5ezopb.cloudfront.net/www/v479/product/inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://d13fzx7h5ezopb.cloudfront.net/www/v479/product/polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://d13fzx7h5ezopb.cloudfront.net/www/v479/product/vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://d13fzx7h5ezopb.cloudfront.net/www/v479/product/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get an HTML code of fully loaded body. So I tried implementing puppeteer.

Running `Puppeteer` on node version `v10.15.3`.
Here's my Puppeteer code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox", 
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox", 
        "--user-agent=Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"]
    })
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(sourceUrl)
htmlCode = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML)
console.log(htmlCode)
```

I tried doing:

`await page.goto(sourceUrl, {waitUntil:"networkidle0"})`

`await page.waitForFunction('window.status==="ready"')`

`await page.waitFor(5000)`

None of them seem to work. Results were either empty body/timeout/page crashed

Here's error message

```
(node:966) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Page crashed!
    at Page._onTargetCrashed (/mnt/c/users/junsoo/desktop/pikk/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:216:24)
    at CDPSession.Page.client.on.event (/mnt/c/users/junsoo/desktop/pikk/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:124:56)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at CDPSession.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (/mnt/c/users/junsoo/desktop/pikk/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:200:12)
    at Connection._onMessage (/mnt/c/users/junsoo/desktop/pikk/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:112:17)
    at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener.event (/mnt/c/users/junsoo/desktop/pikk/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:44:24)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/mnt/c/users/junsoo/desktop/pikk/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
```

I am trying to **scrape** this page: https://www.29cm.co.kr/product/178591

Answer (score 2):

I spent few days with debugging this error and my solution is to launch pupeteer with these arguments:

```
const launchOptions = {
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
      "--unlimited-storage",
      "--full-memory-crash-report",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--ignore-certificate-errors",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--lang=en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
      "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36",
    ],
  };
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this stopped my page crashing as well, what was annoying was I could never catch the page crashing, even when wrapping all of my code in try {} catch {} statements, I'm not getting any crashes anymore which is good but still would love to know where in my code it was happening